# How do I make it so users aren't required to type "http://" before the URL?

Tags: ios, swift, browser

So I'm making a web browser for iPhone and it's almost complete (using XCode) and the one thing I haven't been able to find information on is the search feature. It works perfectly if you type "http://" before your URL but I'd prefer users to not have to enter it, just to make things easier. Thanks!

Comment: Add it yourself if they don't.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to convert the string to NSURL and check if the scheme (http://) is there, if not you can add it. Here is an example

```
var urlString = "google.com"
let correcturl = NSURL.init(string: urlString)
if correcturl?.scheme == nil{
    urlString = "http://" + urlString
}
```